# Referenced table is not in dictionary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

When I scaffold my database get the following error:

```
Referenced table `contentcategory` is not in dictionary.
Referenced table `contentcategory` is not in dictionary.
Referenced table `contenttype` is not in dictionary.
Referenced table `content` is not in dictionary.
```

I Use Mysql and `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely to be a casing issue, where MySQL assumes the table name to be `contentcategory` for the reference, while it is actually something like `ContentCategory`.

We have a [pull request](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/1017) for this open since April, that looks abandoned by the original contributor.

I will fix the PR and merge it, so that the workaround for this issue will be part of our [nightly builds](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#nightly-builds) as of tomorrow.

The linked PR also contains the information of how this issue can arise:

> Okay, that is in line with what I experienced as well. So manually (either by writing the name in the GUI or by using an `ALTER TABLE` statement directly) adding a reference with different casing (on a server with case insensitive file name handling) or disabling `SQL Identifiers are Case Sensitive` [in MySQL Workbench] can lead to this result.

Technically, this is a MySQL or Workbench bug, but we will implement a workaround for it anyway.

Comment: The PR is in the [nightly builds](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#nightly-builds) now and will ship as part of the `3.2.0` release on NuGet.